# Receive UITouchesMoved on a newly added UIView

Tags: ios

In an iOS program I use a UILongPressGestureRecognizer on a large view. Once the long press has been triggered, I remove the large view, and create another thumbnail view centered under my finger. To the user it looks as if the large view has shrunk to a thumbnail that can then be moved.

Once this new thumbnail is created under my finger, I want to be able to move it somewhere else. However, currently, in order to move it I have to lift my finger up and place it back down on the thumbnail in order to get UITouchesBegan/UITouchesMoved messages to be sent.

How can I ensure that UITouchesMoved start to be sent to the newly created view, without having to re-touch the screen? Or what other workaround should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason not to actually shrink the view, as this is the effect you seem to be after anyways? This would also enable you to easily use a short animation for this to get a "Apple-like" UX.

Comment: I had just thought of that. Beryllium's trick is equally good, especially if I wasn't interested in combining the code from the two subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

You cann't do it without touch up. When you down your finger to large view, then this view will receive all move events until you touch up finger.

But there is a one trick - your large view continues to receive events when you move your finger on the screen. You can get access to all new coordinates and set it to thumbnail. It will like you moving thumbnail but in fact you will interact only with large view.